# Morse theory for vector-valued functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, morse-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^k$ be a smooth function. I have seen quite a few books for Morse theory for $f$ when $k=1$. Is there a generalization to $k\geq2$? When $k=1$, we can define a Morse function $f$ by checking the eigenvalues of its Hessian at its critical points. What is the corresponding concept of (non-)degeneracy of critical points when $k\geq 2$? Is there a  normal (quadratic) form of $f$ near its nondengerate critical points when $k\geq 2$, as given in the classical Morse lemma? Any references will also be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might want Cerf theory.

Answer (score 3):

There is a vast literature on singularities, like:

- Gibson, Christopher G.; Wirthmüller, Klaus; du Plessis, Andrew A.; Looijenga, Eduard J. N. Topological stability of smooth mappings. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 552. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1976
- Arnold, V. I.; Gusein-Zade, S. M.; Varchenko, A. N. Singularities of differentiable maps. Volume 1. Classification of critical points, caustics and wave fronts.  Birkhäuser 1985, 2012
- Arnold, V. I.; Gusein-Zade, S. M.; Varchenko, A. N. Singularities of differentiable maps. Volume 2. Monodromy and asymptotics of integrals. Birkhäuser 1988, 2012.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in

[Modification of Morse lemma with two functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232687/modification-of-morse-lemma-with-two-functions)

shows that this doesn't work in general (depending on what you mean)